# Useless Pending Changes in Visual Studio 2010 with dark theme

Tags: visual-studio-2010, themes

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and since a dark theme is supported from Visual Studio 2012, I had to use some special extension tool which does theme changes.

But unfortunately there is a problem with Pending Changes window because text and backgroud color of a changed files (left column) are the same so filenames are invisible.

Microsoft react to this issue in a way that Visual Studio 2010 does not support dark theme and if somebody changed the theme using some extension, it is not their problem.

I am sending a screenshot of the Pending Changes. Do you have any idea how to solve it? No, I do not want to upgrade Visual Studio from 2010 to 2012 and I want to have dark theme (it is much better than normal). Thanks.

[image]